# How to generate an SQL file with DBMS_DATAPUMP

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, export

I am trying to generate an SQL file with the `DBMS_DATAPUMP` api. This tasks is specifically adressed in Oracle support Note 1519981.1 (*How To Generate A SQL File Using The DBMS_DATAPUMP API*).

When I copy/paste the code found in the mentioned document, it fails on line 5 with a rather obscure

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-39001: invalid argument value
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 79
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_DATAPUMP", line 3444
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_DATAPUMP", line 3693
ORA-06512: at line 5
```

The line in question, that is line 5, is `DBMS_DATAPUMP.add_file(...)` with the parameter `filetype => DBMS_DATAPUMP.KU$_FILE_TYPE_SQL_FILE`.

I have run the script with a user that has DBA privileges.

I have also created an Oracle directory named `MYDIR`. The OS directory it points to exists and is writeable.

The complete code that fails is (copied from the note):

```
DECLARE
  h1 NUMBER;
BEGIN
  h1 := DBMS_DATAPUMP.open(operation => 'SQL_FILE', job_mode => 'SCHEMA', job_name => 'j2');
 DBMS_DATAPUMP.add_file(handle => h1,
   filename => 'scott.dmp',
   directory => 'MYDIR',
   filetype => DBMS_DATAPUMP.KU$_FILE_TYPE_DUMP_FILE);
 DBMS_DATAPUMP.add_file(handle => h1,
   filename => 'scott.sql',
   directory => 'MYDIR',
   filetype => DBMS_DATAPUMP.KU$_FILE_TYPE_SQL_FILE );
 DBMS_DATAPUMP.start_job(handle => h1, skip_current => 0, abort_step => 0);
 DBMS_DATAPUMP.detach(handle => h1);
END;
/
```

The version is *11.2.0.1*.

Comment: Please show us the complete code that calls `dbms_datapump`

Comment: Hi René, good to see you back. What Oracle version?

Comment: @Phil the version is 11.2.0.1

Comment: As a workaround, replace `KU$_FILE_TYPE_DUMP_FILE` with `1` and `KU$_FILE_TYPE_SQL_FILE` with 4. Just while I think a bit more :)

Comment: Oh, wait a second, do you need a separate handle for each file?

Comment: Try `job_mode => 'FULL'`

Comment: I tried your code, substituted the directory name and file name, and I get a sql file. Can you check if your directory_name exists, you have read/write permissions on that directory and the dumpfile specified also exists in that directory (in the correct case, if applicable)? forgot to add, i tried it in 12.1, unfortunately I have no 11.2.0.1 databases left to play with. 11.2.0.4 is the lowest i have.

Comment: Following works in 11.2, so perhaps it will work for you as well `DECLARE
  h1 NUMBER;
BEGIN
  h1 := DBMS_DATAPUMP.OPEN ('SQL_FILE', 'FULL', '', 'RAJTEST1');
  DBMS_DATAPUMP.ADD_FILE (h1, 'k.%u.dmp', 'DIREXP', null, 1, null);
  DBMS_DATAPUMP.ADD_FILE (h1, 'k1.sql', 'DIREXP', null, 4, null);
  DBMS_DATAPUMP.START_JOB (h1);
  DBMS_DATAPUMP.detach(handle => h1);
END;
/`  tried to add formatting

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I didn't realise that creating such an export file consists of two steps. First, an ordinary dump file must be created, then this dump file is used to create an sql file.

Since I didn't have such a dump file, the script as posted would not work.

Here are the two steps, so that an sql file can be created

```
declare

  datapump_job number;
  job_state    varchar2(20);

begin

  datapump_job := dbms_datapump.open(
    operation    => 'EXPORT',
    job_mode     => 'SCHEMA',
    remote_link  =>  null,
    job_name     => 'Export dump file',
    version      => 'LATEST'
  );

  dbms_output.put_line('datapump_job: ' || datapump_job);


  dbms_datapump.add_file(
    handle    =>  datapump_job,
    filename  => 'export.dmp',
    directory => 'DATAPUMP_DIR',
    filetype  =>  dbms_datapump.ku$_file_type_dump_file);


  dbms_datapump.start_job(
    handle       => datapump_job,
    skip_current => 0,
    abort_step   => 0);

  dbms_datapump.wait_for_job(datapump_job, job_state);

  dbms_output.put_line('Job state: ' || job_state);

  dbms_datapump.detach(datapump_job);

end;
/
```

and the script that creates the sql file:

```
declare

  datapump_job number;
  job_state    varchar2(20);

begin

  datapump_job := dbms_datapump.open(
    operation    => 'SQL_FILE',
    job_mode     => 'SCHEMA',
    remote_link  =>  null,
    job_name     => 'Export SQL file',
    version      => 'LATEST'
  );

  dbms_output.put_line('datapump_job: ' || datapump_job);

  dbms_datapump.add_file(
    handle    =>  datapump_job,
    filename  => 'export.dmp',
    directory => 'DATAPUMP_DIR',
    filetype  =>  dbms_datapump.ku$_file_type_dump_file);

  dbms_datapump.add_file(
    handle    =>  datapump_job,
    filename  => 'schema.sql',
    directory => 'DATAPUMP_DIR',
    filetype  =>  dbms_datapump.ku$_file_type_sql_file);

  dbms_datapump.start_job(
    handle       => datapump_job,
    skip_current => 0,
    abort_step   => 0);

  dbms_datapump.wait_for_job(datapump_job, job_state);

  dbms_output.put_line('Job state: ' || job_state);

  dbms_datapump.detach(datapump_job);

end;
```

Comment: If you _only_ do this to get the SQL for the schema, you might want to add `dbms_datapump.data_filter(handle => datapump_job, name => 'INCLUDE_ROWS', value => 0);` (before starting the export job). Using that, no data will be exported which should be faster. Depending on what kind of SQL script you are after, you should also look into `dbms_metadata` - it can generate the SQL for everything(?) without the need to export first.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for the tip, much appreciated!